# How do I make a loading bar that updates and adds a percentage every time a picture has loaded

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I make a loading bar that updates and adds a percentage every time a picture has loaded? Also it would know how many pictures there are and calculate one the percentage of one picture.

I've also tried with jquery.

Thanks!

```
    <?php 
echo 'loaded: ' . $countImageLoaded;
?>
<div style="display:none;" id="images">

<div class="row"> 
<?php
$countImageLoaded= 0 ;
$dirname = "files/pictures/files/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.*");

foreach($images as $image) {
    //echo '<div class="column"><img src="'.$image.'" style="width:100%"></div>';
    $countImageLoaded++;
} 

?>
<script>

window.onload = function() 
  { document.getElementById("images").style.display = "block"; }


var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}


function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A picture has loaded where? In the browser?

Comment: Every time it finds a picture

Comment: This is not helping. More details please. Finds what, where, how?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, what i would do is make an animated loading bar, the client doesn't necessarily need to know the actual progress. It just animates a progress bar, and stays at 99% until the function is completed. Doesn't need to correlate with the actual progress, just something to keep the user patient.

Comment: I mean yea... But the website won't be published to the public. I need for a local website, and I do need it to display the real percentage. Not some loading bar that will stay on 99% for a minute and if I have a lot more pictures to load. But thanks for the answer.